# How to exclude dependencies from maven assembly plugin : jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven's assembly plugin enables the creation of a big jar including all dependencies with descriptorRef `jar-with-dependencies`.

How can one exclude some of these dependencies? It seems like it does not have such a configuration? Is there another solution?

Comment: Related: if you have excluded some deps at POM level and they are still being included in the assembly output, check out your assembly plugin version. [Pre-3.1.1 has suffered from an exclusion related bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461192/how-to-have-maven-assembly-plugin-respect-the-exclusions-defined-in-pom-xml#49799612)
, and a surprisingly large number of us still use older versions (mine was 2.4 until I explicitly looked this up).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html) indicates one way to do this:

```
 <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      ....
      <excludes>
        <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
        <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
    ....
  </dependencySets>
```

Essentially we would use the `excludes` option available in `dependencySet`.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-component.html

Comment: This gives an error: "Unrecognised tag: 'dependencySets'" for maven3

Comment: This example assumes that I know where dependencySets goes in the pom.xml. A full example would have been helpful.

Comment: The issue here (after 7 yaers) is that this only goes in the assembly definition file, which is not used with 'jar-with-dependencies.'

Answer (score 53):

Add the `<scope>provided</scope>` to the dependencies you don't want included in the jar-with-dependencies, e.g.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution and is consistent with WAR targets as well

Comment: I tried this with javafx-controls and javafx-fxml libraries in two different projects.  It worked beautifully in the first project.  But on the second one, it failed with the compiling many errors such as 'package javafx.beans doesn't exist'.  Don't know why.

Comment: Funny to see how I upvoted this answer and now I am having a problem with `provided` JARs being included in the output JAR

Answer (score 27):

You should use the `excludes` option available in `dependencySet`. 
Follow below.:

Example in your **pom.xml**:

```
...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>../final/${project.artifactId}</finalName>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.entrerprise.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
...
```

Now in your new file **jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml** (where **dependencySet** lives):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
        <id>jar-with-dependencies-and-exclude-classes</id>
        <formats>
          <format>jar</format>
        </formats>
        <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
        <dependencySets>
          <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
              <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
              <exclude>org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh</exclude>
            </excludes>
           </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>
        <fileSets>
          <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
          </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
      </assembly>
```

That's all.

Comment: Better answer than Raghuram's

Comment: Note that the final jar would be like `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-<descriptor-id>.jar`, just as the original jar is `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. If the jar name matters, change the descriptor id to match the original.

Comment: Great answer, but it would have been nice to know how this relates to the normal jar-with-dependencies descriptor. I managed to dig up the following, for those interested in compare to <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>, compared to using the custom <descriptor> in this example: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to switch to the much more feature rich `maven-shade-plugin` which can do this without any external assembly files or marking as "provided" (which may not be what you want as it forces users to have that dependency in their pom). Here is an example:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude><group-id>:<artifact-id>:<classifier></exclude>
                <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html

Note that this wont make a `jar-with-dependencies` but rather an `original-jar...` and then just the regular output jar. This plugin even lets you filter out specific classes.