# How to Exclude Certain Jar Dependencies while creating jar without using maven?

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I am working on a core Java project. I am writing an Apache Storm topology and need to exclude storm jars while binding the topology into jar. Is there any way to do this without using maven? I know with maven we can use `<scope>provided</scope>` but I need an alternative to this.

PS: I am using Eclipse.

Comment: How do you build your jar if not using maven?

Comment: by exporting it to executable jar using eclipse

Comment: Try to export to "regular" jar file (ie, "JAR file" no "Runnable JAR file").

Comment: Exporting as regular jar, where can we mention which jars need to be excluded?

Comment: Exporting as regular jar, will no include any dependencies. If you need to have some but not all dependencies, I guess that Eclipse does not support this. I would really recommend to use maven (or another build tool -- maybe ant)

Comment: Why not try the `<exclusions>` tag in maven ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Maven instead of Gradle, and you come here for excluding lib of Storm in building, I have the solution and a working example.

The [documentation of Storm](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html) tells us to exclude the Storm dependency and provides [a link to a page of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html), which explains how to do it but it lacks a full example. It turns out that **we have to create another XML file as the descriptor of assembly configuration, instead of putting the configuration directly in the `pom.xml`, even when Eclipse does not complain about putting the two files together.**

Here is how:

We have our `pom.xml` with `assembly` plugins, pointing to another descriptor xml file:

```
<plugin>                                                                                
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>                                      
    <executions>                                                                        
        <execution>                                                                     
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->         
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->                 
            <goals>                                                                     
                <goal>single</goal>                                                     
            </goals>                                                                    
        </execution>                                                                    
    </executions>                                                                       
    <configuration>                                                                     
        <descriptors>                                                                   
            <descriptor>/src/main/resources/exclude-storm.xml</descriptor>              
        </descriptors>                                                                  
        <archive>                                                                       
            <manifest>                                                                  
                <mainClass>path.to.main.class</mainClass> 
            </manifest>                                                                 
        </archive>                                                                      
        <descriptorRefs>                                                                
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>                        
        </descriptorRefs>                                                               
    </configuration>                                                                    
</plugin>
```

Note the part of: (should be complete path)

```
<descriptors>                                                                   
    <descriptor>/src/main/resources/exclude-storm.xml</descriptor>              
</descriptors>
```

And in this path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>exclude-storm</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>compile</scope>   <!-- note here!!!! -->
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:1.1.1</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Here we add the settings of Maven doc page.

The most important thing: format of exclusion: should be: ([ref](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet))

```
groupId:artifactId:type[:classifier]:version
```

And the scope! `runtime` is default, I changed it to `compile` and it works.

At last, when you compile, use:

```
clean assembly:assembly
```

And turn on debug output to see full output in console. If you:

- have a successful build
- search the output and haven't found anything like: `[WARNING]The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter: o 'org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:1.1.1'.`
- the jar contains no `default.yaml`

Then you know you have succeeded.

Thanks for the inspiration of another question and answers: [How to exclude dependencies from maven assembly plugin : jar-with-dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209903/how-to-exclude-dependencies-from-maven-assembly-plugin-jar-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) for compiling the JAR files for topologies. It allows you to exclude certain files when generating JAR files.

The example below shows the set-up that I use in my build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'


    configurations {
        provided
        compile.extendsFrom provided
    }

    jar {
        dependsOn configurations.runtime

        from {
            (configurations.runtime - configurations.provided).collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
        }

        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.myclass'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        provided files('./lib/asm-4.0.jar')
        provided files('./lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar')
        # ... The rest of the Storm jars found in the lib directory of your storm installation
    }
```

By default the directory structure Gradle expects is

```
MyProjectName
    - build.gradle
    - src
       - main
            - java
                - [Your Java Files]
            - resources
                - resources
                    - [Mutlilang files / other resources]
```

From the command line when you run **gradle build** in the directory containing your build.gradle file a JAR file should be generated under .\build\libs

There is also a [Gradle plugin for eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0)