# Apache Storm - How to exclude storm jar in Maven in production cluster

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

As per the [documentation](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html), when we deploy Storm topology to production cluster, we have to exclude from Maven the jar of Storm, because it will be in the classpath already, and if we don't do this, there will be an error like `multiple default.yaml in classpath`.

So how can we do it? The documentation has provided some details but not clear enough. When we configure the maven and build the jar, the `org.apache.storm` jar is still included, we have a `default.yaml` in the jar, and, actually, if we turn on the debug output in building, we will see a warning like:

```
[WARNING]The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter: o 'org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:1.1.1'.
```

Changed the scope of the dependency `org.apache.storm` to `provided`, and it does not work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of Storm](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html) tells us to exclude the Storm dependency and provides [a link to a page of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html), which explains how to do it but it lacks a full example. It turns out that **we have to create another XML file as the descriptor of assembly configuration, instead of putting the configuration directly in the `pom.xml`, even when Eclipse does not complain about putting the two files together.**

And, in the second xml file, the scope should be `compile` instead of `runtime`.

Here is how:

We have our `pom.xml` with `assembly` plugins, pointing to another descriptor xml file:

```
<plugin>                                                                                
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>                                      
    <executions>                                                                        
        <execution>                                                                     
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->         
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->                 
            <goals>                                                                     
                <goal>single</goal>                                                     
            </goals>                                                                    
        </execution>                                                                    
    </executions>                                                                       
    <configuration>                                                                     
        <descriptors>                                                                   
            <descriptor>/src/main/resources/exclude-storm.xml</descriptor>              
        </descriptors>                                                                  
        <archive>                                                                       
            <manifest>                                                                  
                <mainClass>path.to.main.class</mainClass> 
            </manifest>                                                                 
        </archive>                                                                      
        <descriptorRefs>                                                                
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>                        
        </descriptorRefs>                                                               
    </configuration>                                                                    
</plugin>
```

Note the part of: (should be complete path)

```
<descriptors>                                                                   
    <descriptor>/src/main/resources/exclude-storm.xml</descriptor>              
</descriptors>
```

And in this path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>exclude-storm</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>compile</scope>   <!-- note here!!!! -->
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:1.1.1</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Here we add the settings of Maven doc page.

The most important thing: format of exclusion: should be: ([ref](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet))

```
groupId:artifactId:type[:classifier]:version
```

And the scope! `runtime` is default, I changed it to `compile` and it works.

At last, when you compile, use:

```
clean assembly:assembly
```

And turn on debug output to see full output in console. If you:

- have a successful build
- search the output and haven't found anything like: `[WARNING]The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter: o 'org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:1.1.1'.`
- the jar contains no `default.yaml`

Then you know you have succeeded.

Thanks for the inspiration of another question and answers: [How to exclude dependencies from maven assembly plugin : jar-with-dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209903/how-to-exclude-dependencies-from-maven-assembly-plugin-jar-with-dependencies)

Comment: And, if you run `storm jar jar-file main-class-path` and fails with `cannot load main class` error, change `storm` to full path of storm executable, and `jar-file` with full path, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy you figured out how to do it with the assembly plugin. An easier solution is to use the shade plugin to create your fat jar. There are complete examples of how to configure the pom in the Storm examples directory (which is also included in the Storm binary distribution)

See for instance https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/80cc88112bf4fab34571ebff03782b759d112288/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples/pom.xml#L94

When you use the shade plugin, the provided scope for storm-core will be respected when creating the fat jar.

Comment: Thanks for comment. With the fat jar, will there be the problem referred in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven#answer-32316071? I mean, `class files with same path overwriting each other`?

Comment: Yes, but that's going to be a problem no matter whether you use the assembly plugin or shade. They both produce a fat jar.